# How to put while loop with arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create a program which takes an ISBN number for a user. The variable for ISBN is an array and if use enter 0 for ISBN the program should ends. But the program keep running even when I enter 0 for ISBN number:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int isbnNumber[100];
int i = 1;

printf("ISBN number: ");
scanf("%d", &isbnNumber[0]);

while (isbnNumber[100] != 0) {

    printf("ISBN number: ");
    i++;
    scanf("%d", &isbnNumber[i]);


 }
}
```

Comment: Please post your actual code - you have no `main()`

Comment: `int i = 0;` and `isbnNumber[100] != 0` --> `isbnNumber[i] != 0`

Comment: @mathematician1975 oh ya, it was a typo.

Comment: In addtion to what @RSahu said, you also need to check the return value of `scanf`. Otherwise you will get Undefined Behaviour if the user enters a non-integer value - because `scanf` will fail in that case and `isbnNumber[i]` will be unintialised when checked in the `while` condition.

Comment: And note that indexes in C go from `0 .. (length - 1)`. last valid index for  `int array[100]` is `99`, not `100`! You invoke undefined behaviour. Avoid this like hell, heaven, clowns, or whatever you fear most.

Comment: ^ I fear buffer overflow attacks most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `isbnNumber[100]` checks the 101st element of the array. The loop will only exit if you enter 0 on the 100th iteration.

Also, it should be noted that `isbnNumber[100]` is not an element of the `isbnNumber` array. Array indexing begins at zero, so the last element in `isbnNumber` is `isbnNumber[99]`. Accessing elements past the end of the array is undefined behavior. If you were entering 0 on the 100th iteration, this is why the loop didn't exit.

Furthermore, you really should have something to prevent the loop from running past the end of the array. Here's how you would have the loop run until you enter 0 or you've hit the end of the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    printf("ISBN number: ");
    scanf("%d", &isbnNumber[i]);
    if (isbnNumber[i] == 0)
        break;
}
```